# Thinning hair on cats back

Tags: cats, health

I've noticed that my cat has thinning hairs on her mid back. The rest of the fur on her is soft but this one area has fur that feels more like hair and I can see through to her skin if I push the fur aside.

I've also noticed that her purr has changed and that she purrs within a few seconds of me petting her (this never used to happen before). I don't know if this hair thinning will continue and lead to hair loss so I'm wondering if anyone can explain what is happening here.

Comment: see http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/skin/c_ct_alopecia

Comment: Over-grooming can cause thinning as the cat licks away the undercoat, and leaves behind only the thicker guard hairs. If she is seeking more attention she might be lonely or anxious. You should rule out disease processes first, but it may very well be a behavior problem caused by stress. Your vet is a good resource for more information.

Comment: My cat does not groom the area that has thinning hairs. Although recently she has been  seeking my attention more and meowing at night. Do you think stress could be the reason for this? As a side note, I've also started to cut down the amount of calories she consumes in a day, which has been a necessary change for her weight loss. This started about a month ago. Do you think this has something to do with the fur problem? @fmorales

Comment: How has the purring changed? How old is the cat? Have there been any other changes? Can you please post a pic?

Comment: @newuser101 Stress, fleas, food allergies, environmental allergies are all possibilities if she is not over grooming. Your vet can help you sort out the cause.

Comment: @YvetteColomb The purring has changed in the sense that it has become more frequent so that when i pet her for a few seconds, she'll start to purr. I don't know how to describe the change specifically but I can say that the same thing happened when my cat had an abscess. Before i discovered the abscess i noticed that her purr had changed in the same way. I read somewhere that purrs can indicate contentment or pain, and for some reason i have a feeling that she's purring to indicate that she's in pain, like she was with her abscess.

Comment: @YvetteColomb She is 4 years old, spayed, 19 pounds. We've put her on a new meal schedule, before she used to free fed but since a month now we've been giving fewer calories and more scheduled meals.

Comment: @fmorales Thank you. I think that stress may be the cause, but allergies and fleas could very well be the issue here.

Comment: Has she been wormed? It sounds a little odd - perhaps a trip to the vet?

Comment: Some blood work might be good. Check CBC and White Count.

Comment: How old is your cat? I suppose she needs vitamins. Gave them to her for some time or take her to the vet. Also, I think your cat could hurt herself, playing on the street or with the other animals. It happens sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed a similar problem with my female cat. She generally has a soft and fluffy coat, but the fur along her spine has become coarse and is significantly thinner than the rest of her body. As you described, I can brush her hair to the side and see her bare skin.

I actually just brought her to the veterinarian today (for an unrelated issue) and asked about this. We came to the conclusion that, in my cat's case, it is most likely either a seasonal allergy-related issue or an issue with the transition from her winter coat to her spring coat. She is an indoor cat, but still goes through quite a seasonal transition. She had the same issue last spring, but I assumed it was from "over-grooming" at the time.

If this is the first spring that you have had your cat and you live in an area that undergoes seasonal changes, then it could be the same problem. In which case, you just have to wait it out for a couple of weeks and you should see some improvement!

Answer (score 1):

The first time this happened to my cat it was because of fleas, have you checked your cat very thoroughly for fleas or other pests?

More recently her thinning fur is from over grooming and dandruff, the dandruff is apparently related to her diabetes.  If you are certain that its not fleas or anything like that ( or even if it is) I would get your cat to a vet, they will hopefully be able to determine what, if anything, is wrong. Meanwhile try to discourage them from grooming the area excessively.